# How do I delete multiple people from my tree on Ancestry.com?

Tags: ancestry.com

I spec-ed out a branch on my family tree on Ancestry.com but later found out that the branch was in error. I can delete each person individually, but it's a long process to edit/delete each one.

Is there a way to prune a whole branch or just select a group of people to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a branch of the tree by deleting the person at the base of the branch.  **Edit per comments:  This will not delete the actual people from your list of individuals though.**  There is not a way to delete multiple people at a time from both places.

Before:

[image]

Hover over Person2 and click Edit:

[image]

Click "Delete this person":

[image]

Persons 2, 4, and 5 have been deleted.

Comment: I like how there are leafs on Persons 1, 2, 3, and 5!

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then.  The people are gone from the visual tree, but when I look at all the people in the tree in listview form, Person 4 and 5 are still there.  Orphaned.

Comment: Huh.  You're right.  I've been using FTM lately, but those are the steps I remember taking.  When I just tried it and saw the tree change as above, I didn't think to check the list. :|